# Relay communication Block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Im trying to prepare a research note on the relay communication field, 
I tried to draw the following diagram in LaTeX (TikZ) but I didn't succeed to draw it good enough...

Can anybody help me to draw the following diagram in LaTeX? The 'H's are bold for example

```
${\mathbf H}_0$...
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look a tikz (http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) and the examples posted on TeXample (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/) for examples.

Comment: Thank you so much Laura, The book seems to be very helpful. I wish I could read it until tomorrow(my deadline);)

Comment: Maybe draw it using Inkscape and then use the tikz exporter?  code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/

Comment: Please include the version you don't like so users here can make it better. Otherwise starting from scratch is really not fun.

Comment: ass an addition on @rickhg12hs: you can also draw it using DIA and then export it as tikz...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know I shouldn't do it, but if you promise to start studying `TiKZ` the day after your deadline ( ;-) ) you can use next code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\newcommand{\antena}{--++(3mm,0)--++(30:5mm)--++(-90:5mm)--++(150:5mm);}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',
box/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm},
line/.style={->,shorten >=3mm, shorten <=3mm}]

\node[box] (source) {Source};
\node[box, right=5cm of source] (dest) {Destination};
\node[box, above right=2.5cm and 2.5cm of source, anchor=center] (relay) {Relay};

\draw[line] (source.north) -- node[above,sloped] {First Time Slot} node[below,sloped]{${\mathbf H}_0$} (relay.west); 

\draw[line] ([xshift=5mm]source.east) -- node[below,sloped] {First Time Slot} node[above,sloped]{${\mathbf H}_1$} ([xshift=-5mm]dest.west); 

\draw[line,dashed] (relay.east) -- node[above,sloped] {Second Time Slot} node[below,sloped]{${\mathbf H}_2$} (dest.north); 

\draw (source.20) \antena;
\draw (source.-20) \antena;
\node[right=3mm] at ([yshift=1mm]source.east) {\vdots};

\draw[rotate=180] (dest.160) \antena;
\draw[rotate=180] (dest.-160) \antena;
\node[left=3mm] at ([yshift=1mm]dest.west) {\vdots};

\draw[rotate=-90] (relay.-50) \antena;
\draw[rotate=-90] (relay.230) \antena;
\node[below=3mm] at (relay.south) {\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats good...:) thank you so much.... I promiss....:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of the above code in which the antennas are upward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\newcommand{\antena}{--++(5mm,0)--++(90:3mm)--++(60:5mm)--++(-180:5mm)--++(-60:5mm);} %
\newcommand{\reverseantena}{--++(-5mm,0)--++(90:3mm)--++(60:5mm)--++(-180:5mm)--++(-60:5mm);} %
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',
box/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm},
line/.style={->,shorten >=3mm, shorten <=3mm}]
\node[box] (source) {Source};
\node[box, right=5cm of source] (dest) {Destination};
\node[box, above right=2.5cm and 2.5cm of source, anchor=center] (relay) {Relay};
\draw[line] (source.north) -- node[above,sloped] {First Time Slot} node[below,sloped]{${\mathbf H}_0$} ([xshift=-4mm,yshift=-4mm]relay.west);
\draw[line] ([xshift=5mm]source.east) -- node[below,sloped] {First Time Slot} node[above,sloped]{${\mathbf H}_1$} ([xshift=-5mm]dest.west);
\draw[line,dashed, blue] ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-4mm]relay.east) -- node[above,sloped, blue] {Second Time Slot} node[below,sloped]{${\mathbf H}_2$} (dest.north);
\draw (source.20) \antena;
\draw (source.-20) \antena;
\node[right=0mm] at ([yshift=1mm]source.east) {\vdots};
\draw[rotate=0] (dest.160) \reverseantena;
\draw[rotate=0] (dest.-160) \reverseantena;
\node[left=0mm] at ([yshift=1mm]dest.west) {\vdots};
\draw (relay.20) \antena;
\draw (relay.-20) \antena;
\node[right=0mm] at ([yshift=1mm]relay.east) {\vdots};
\draw[rotate=0] (relay.160) \reverseantena;
\draw[rotate=0] (relay.-160) \reverseantena;
\node[left=0mm] at ([yshift=1mm]relay.west) {\vdots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]